# Change style for filteredselectmultiple widget tooltip text

Tags: django

I have used help help-tooltip help-icon in that I want add bootstrap tooltip styles. But not able to do?

For reference I have attached screenshot. Provide solution according to that.in following image that question mark shows tooltip text and i want add bootstrap tooltip style in that text .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uS3PW.jpg)

Add bootstrap tooltip style for tooltip